# nameof operator VS .ToString() for Enums

Tags: c#, asp.net, enums

I am using nameof operator to get the name of some enums,

but some people in my team using .ToString() to get the name of enums.

I am just wondering about the impact of each way on memory?

Comment: How does calling `.ToString()` on properties give their _name_?

Comment: Two completely different things.

Comment: sorry my bad, it's enums only

Comment: i'd say it would be an insignificant difference that you have no need to be concerned about.

Comment: minor (so as to probably be unmeasurable) difference is that `nameof` acts at compile time.

Comment: .ToString() will work on *variables* of type `YourEnum`, `nameof` would give the name of the variable

Comment: I know that the two ways return string, so it allocates location in memory, but is there any difference between the two ways?

Comment: The time to worry about memory is when you profile your code and find the memory usage unacceptable, then to isolate the source of the issues and work to resolve them. If you ever trace a memory issue down to whether you're using `nameof` or `Enum.Value.ToString()` then congratulations. But at that point, you measure both and use the one that works best for you. I doubt it'll even happen. The whole point of using a managed language is to be able to pretend we're working on a machine with infinite memory.